# discord.py bot works for message event or ping command, cannot do both simultaneously

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted the bot to say pong when I do the command `!ping`, and when someone says `kiddo` in a message, the bot will reply by a hello. But when I comment out the second command, the ping command works, and when I uncomment the kiddo event, the ping command stops working, what is going wrong here?

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Pong!")
    await message.edit(content = f"Pong! {round(client.latency*1000,2)} ms")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("kiddo"):
        await message.channel.send("hello?")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple fix to that is to add `client.process_commands(message)` to your code like this:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Pong!")
    await message.edit(content = f"Pong! {round(client.latency*1000,2)} ms")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("kiddo"):
        await message.channel.send("hello?")
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```